# Testing regime change in SAS

Tags: regression, sas

I have two samples, A and B. I run the same model for A and B separately to obtain the estimates. I now want to test whether the parameters for models in A are the same with the parameters in B using SAS. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much detail given in your question (what type of model?) and there is probably a way to combine your data into one full model to test for differences between A and B.

Having said that you could construct confidence intervals for the difference between the two parameters and see if 0 is in the confidence interval.  This shouldn't be too hard since SAS will give you the standard error associated with each estimate.

Edit:

If it is a simple linear model you could bring in a dummy variable main effect (1 for group B, 0 for group A).  This would test for same intercepts.  Interacting the dummy variable with the other parameter main effect will test for same slope.

Comment: Suppose it is a simple linear model. Will you give me the reference?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pool your data and create a dummy variable that allows you to identify the two samples.

First, estimate the model:

$$Y = b_0 + b_1*X$$

Second, estimate the model:

$$Y = b_0 + b_1*X + b_2*D + b_3 * (D*X)$$

Where $D$ is the dummy variable that identifies the two samples

Compute the test statistic

$$ \frac{SSR_1 - SSR_2}{SSR_1} * \frac{n-2*k}{k}  $$

Where $SSR_1$ and $SSR_2$ are the sum of squared residuals of models 1 and 2, $n$ is the number of observations and $k$ is the number of parameters estimated in model 1 (here: $k = 2$). This test statistic follows an F distribution with degrees of freedom $(k, n-2*k)$.

This procedure can be generalized to the more than one explanatory variable.

In SAS you can easily implement this approach using `proc reg`. All the information you need to compute the test statistic can be found in the output of `proc reg`. Note that you could also use the `test` statement:

```
proc reg data = pooled;
model Y = X D XD;
test D = 0, XD = 0;
run;
```

In econometrics this procedure is called *Chow Test*. You can e.g. refer to Wooldridge's [Introductory Econometrics](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introductory_econometrics.html?id=64vt5TDBNLwC), or any other textbook.